# How do I get Regex to correctly match urls with correct image file names?

Tags: regex

I am trying to update paths of a large document using Regex and I am trying to get the match to match all img Src tags that include the file type JPG, PNG

I have useded the following to try get Regex to correctly match:

```
<img src="xanne.nnn.pagespeed.ic.u49smximgo.jpg" alt="test">
<img src="xanne.nnn.pagespeed.ic.u49smximgo.png" alt="test">
```

but it also matches the bottom

```
<img src="xanne.nnn.pagespeed.ic.u49smximgo.webp" alt="test">
<img src="xanne.nnn.pagespeed.ic.u49smximgo.gif" alt="test">
```

When I use the following Regex:

```
<img src="(?=.*(jpg|png)?)
```

Any ideas how I can get it to match only (1 and 2) and not 1,2,3,4?

Comment: What do you want to get as a match? (As in the whole img tag or only the part up to `src="`?)

Comment: Deleted my answer until what you want to match is exactly clear.

Comment: why did someone edit my question title? That wasn't what I asked originally? Updated to original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match only the src attribute value

```
img src="(?=(.*jpg|.*png))
```

[`RegEx Demo`](http://regex101.com/r/oE3xO9/1)

This will match whole line that has of the format shown in 1,2

```
(?=^<img src=".*(jpg|png)").*$
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get Regex to correctly match **urls** with correct image file names?

Get the matched group from index 1 that is captured using parenthesis in below regex pattern:

```
<img src="(.*\.(jpg|png))"
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/hA5oL3/3)

---

OR try without grouping as well using Non-capturing group and [**Positive Look Behind**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

```
(?<=<img src=").*\.(?:jpg|png)(?=")
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/hA5oL3/4)