# How do I get Regex to correctly match the image tags with jpg/ png image paths in?

Tags: regex

I am trying to update paths of a large document using Regex and I am trying to get the match to match all  that include the file type JPG, PNG

I have useded the following to try get Regex to correctly match:

```html
 1.   <img src="xanne.nnn.pagespeed.ic.u49smximgo.jpg" alt="test">
  2.   <img src="xanne.nnn.pagespeed.ic.u49smximgo.png" alt="test">
```

but it also matches the bottom

```html
  3.   <img src="xanne.nnn.pagespeed.ic.u49smximgo.webp" alt="test">]
 4.    <img src="xanne.nnn.pagespeed.ic.u49smximgo.gif" alt="test">
```

When I use the following Regex:

```
<img src="(?=.*(jpg|png)?)
```

Any ideas how I can get it to match only (1 and 2) and not 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Take out the last `?`

Comment: Why do you have duplicate questions?

Comment: When I submitted it, the page went to a 404 so I thought it hadnt gone through.Can someone just delete it?

Comment: Best Answer was on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615417/how-do-i-get-regex-to-correctly-match-urls-with-correct-image-file-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the `?` at the end. It is making the `jpg` or `png` match allow for it to not be there. Taking the `?` out enforces one or the other to be there.

```
<img src="(?=.*(jpg|png))
                       ^^
```